# Problema ao verificar se um tipo any é undefined no Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estou tendo um problema ao verificar se uma variável é undefined no seguinte código em typescript.

```
Atendimento:any;

this.Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao == undefined ? '' : this.Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao;
```

Se o Atendimento não retorna nada do webservice, consequentemente setando o Atendimento para undefined, o seguinte código dá erro dizendo que a variável this.Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao está undefined, ignorando o if, alguém saberia como resolver(Sem eu precisar declarar uma classe modelo, pois fazer isso daria um trabalhão no sistema) e por que ocorre esse problema?

Comment: Tem alguma forma de checar isso em um if?

Comment: Pedro o uso do Any em Typescript em muitas ocasiões é considerada uma má prática, exatamente como neste seu caso, você tem um objeto que contém um outro objeto que contém algumas propriedades, o ideal seria ter todos os nós tipados para evitar os temidos Undefined e não ter que ficar fazendo If nó por nó como no exemplo do nosso amigo Rodrigo.

Comment: Se não me engano é possível usar algo como `this.?Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao` mas não me lembro como funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer a verificação a cada nó.

```js
this.Atendimento == undefined || this.Atendimento.Checkout == undefined || this.Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao == undefined ? '' : this.Atendimento.Checkout.Observacao;
```

Comment: Pensei que tivesse um código menor para fazer essas validações, mas obrigado, ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Se não estiveres a instanciar a tua variavel dentro de algum ctor, podes fazer logo. Se WebService garantir que o object Checkout é instanciado, não irás precisar de mais verificações sem ser se as observações são vazias ou com valor.

```
this.Atendimento === undefined ? alert("null") : alert("instanciado");
```

Exemplo [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Atendimento%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20()%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.test%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Atendimento%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20alert(%22null%22)%20%3A%20alert(%22instanciado%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20d%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d.test()%3B%0D%0A%7D)()%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o que está acontecendo é que `this.Atendimento.Checkout` está undefined, logo ao tentar acessar o atributo "Observacao" o erro é disparado.
Faça múltiplas validações como na resposta do Rodrigo Costa.